# The P-value approach to hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

When we do a hypothesis testing we follow the steps given below:

Step 1: Form a null hypothesis $H_0 : \mu_{\bar{x}} = K$. Form an alternative hypothesis $H_1 : \mu \neq K$

Step 2: Decide a significance level $\alpha$.

Step 3: Take a sample of size $n$, find its mean $\bar{x}$.

$\color{red}{Step~ 4} $: From the known population mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, calculate
$$
\mu_{\bar{x}} = \mu \\
\sigma_{\bar{x}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Step 5: Convert $\bar{x}$ to standard units as follows
$$
z = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_{\bar{x}} }{\sigma_{\bar{x}}}$$

Step 6: Find the probability of $z$

If $P(z) \gt \alpha$, do not reject the null hypothesis, else reject it.

My doubt is quite foundational here, what would we do by doing a test of any kind when we already know such great things about population: its mean and its standard deviation. And how would be ever be able to know the standard deviation of the population?

Let me illustrate my question through an example:

I told my friend that on average I make 5 successful 3-pointer in a basket-ball game. That would me by $K$ and $\mu$. And how can I tell him $\sigma$, it doesn't make any sense (after all the population size is also not decided, I'm simply telling him what I have observed since my childhood)? If he wants to check, he would ask me to play a few games (let's say 10 games), and he would count the number of successful 3-pointer shots, but he wouldn't be able to convert his $\bar{x}$ to $z$, because I cannot provide him with $\sigma$. Thus, the test of hypothesis through $P-value$ approach is totally inapplicable.

Can you please show me in what type of research we find the P-value approach helpful when all the research is to be done by one person only? (By that I mean, the person doesn't want to check a government data, but have to come up with his own hypothesis and data. Wouldn't population mean, in itself, be the gem a researcher seeks for?)

Comment: Your step 4 (and hence 5) is wrong. Your step 6 is not exactly correct either. See for example https://www.jmp.com/en_sg/statistics-knowledge-portal/t-test/one-sample-t-test.html, or any other result of the search for one-sample t-test.

Comment: @ocram I don't think I'm wrong. Who is talking about t-test?

Comment: The post goes astray immediately at step 1 - you begin with "When we do a hypothesis testing we follow the steps given below" but then step 1 is specifically about testing a hypothesis about *a single mean*. This immediately takes you from what started as a general statement about hypothesis testing to something that is not. Either the words immediately before step 1 are too general or the rest is too specific.

Comment: @Glen_b I guess the title is not visible to some users.

Comment: To clarify, either all the words prior to  "step 1" (including the title) are too general, or the rest is too specific. Step 1 sets up a specific hypothesis about means, but the title and the words immediately after are completely general, apparently about any hypothesis test for which you can calculate a p value.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t know the true mean. You speculate about what the true mean is and test how reasonable such speculation is. When the data are inconsistent with such speculation, which is quantified by the p-value, you reject your speculation.

Thus, when you subtract $\mu$ from $\bar x$, you are subtracting the speculated mean, not the true mean. Your $\mu_{\bar x}$ notation is confusing. Your speculated mean does not depend on the data. In fact, you should determine your null and alternative hypotheses before you look at the data.

Regarding the variance, it is usually unreasonable to think we would know the variance yet not know the mean, but the z-test with a known variance is easier than a t-test with an unknown variance, so such a test is reasonable to teach to absolute beginners before getting into more practical methodology as the course advances.

Comment: $\mu_{\bar{x}}$ is the mean of sample means, which is equal to the population mean. This notation is used by Weiss in his book.

Comment: How a variance of population is known beforehand? Is it true only in the examples that we do in our textbooks?

Comment: @ConGovDeIn If the book clarifies the $\mu_{\bar x}$ notation. // I can’t think of when we would know the variance but not the mean, so it’s largely a textbook exercise to build up to a more realistic situation, but perhaps there could be such a situation.